# How can I validate the dynamic part of vue-route, with nuxt?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have two pages in my app with names:

1) album_id.vue
2) albums_id.vue

'id' parameter supposed to be a number. The route for first case should look like { name: '/album', params: {id: '123'}}, and for the second - { name: '/albums', params: {id: '123'}}

The issue is - when I reload the page, it treats the url '.../albums123' as { name: '/album', params: {id: 's123'}}.

The question is: 
What is the best way to set a number-validator for the id in this case, using Vue2 and Nuxt?